# My manifest went missing after failing building gradle with Glide Library

Tags: android, gradle, manifest, android-glide

I tried using the Glide library in order to load a profile picture from Facebook, in the gradle I implemented the 4.8.0 version (which is not the latest) and it made this error :

[ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\Paul Jouet\Desktop\ESILV\S5\Mobile Programming\ProjetTest2\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[18,89]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuVM6.png)

My manifest module has disappeared, it is still in my project and I can open it, but not from the 'android' section... When I tried syncing again without the implementation, the error remains, I tried some solutions I found like cleaning the project and rebuild it, but none worked.

[This is how the 'android' section looks like after the failed syncing, the module 'manifest' is missing even though it is still in the same location as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkfr0.png)

Can someone explain to me how this can happen ? It makes no sense to me since I obviously deleted the part causing the problem... The only solution I could find is to recreate a project from scratch and copy paste all my code, but this is not viable since it can happen again.

Thank you for helping !

Edit : here are my manifest and gradle codes

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.projettest2"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
}
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.projettest2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider464643414180175" //I changed the ID
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges= "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried File -> 'Invalidate Caches & Restart' option in your IDE?

Comment: I have tried it, it did not work...

Comment: Could you post your Manifest file? It seems to me that the error is pointing to your manifest itself

Comment: I updated the post, but I made no changes in the manifest, and it was working before the failed sync gradle, so I don't think that is where the error could come from

Comment: Is the comment in your manifest 'I changed the ID' there before? because using double slash `//` is not how you declare a comment in manifest. If so, try deleting that comment and rebuild your project again.

Comment: I managed to get back to normal ! In order to edit the post I erased a comment I made in the manifest, and it synced ! However it worked before even with this comment so I don't really understand why the fact that I tried syncing with an outdated library would create this mess... Anyways, thank you very much for your help ! edit : I saw your last comment just after posting this one, and no it wasn't there but it was another one actually

Comment: Glad it worked!